# Scala class - required property

Tags: scala, traits

I would like to define trait that has const property, for example:

```
trait InitialTest {
    // property would be set here or somewhere else, let's call it typeNumber

   override def toString = typeNumber.toString
}
```

then I would like to set this value for each implementation like:

```
case class InitialTest1 extends InitialTest {
   // set value here like typeNumber = 4
}
```

For each toString function would use impelemetation from trait.
Do you know how can I acheive it?

Comment: What's the problem with `final override def toString`? ; EDIT: Apparently, the question is completely unclear. While I'm trying to find out why you don't simply prepend `final` to the method that you want to have "constant", Mateusz Kubuszok is already answering something completely different...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I might be wrong but from what I understand, he want to: 1 - have implementation-dependent constant value, 2 - toString that is based on that value and is overriden automatically for each implementation, 3 - somehow enforce that in compile time. Basing on examples, I just guessed author did not have a problem with final modifiers, but instead he didn't knew he can have abstract vals.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of achieving it, that I see is:

```
trait MyTrait {

  val myProperty: X // abstract property

  override def toString: String = myProperty.toString
}
```

It would force implementation of the property:

```
class Impl extends MyTrait {

  val myProperty = new X // without that line it doesn't compile
}
```

From there on, one might complicate design further e.g. by splitting the trait with the property from the trait overriding toString with a cake pattern (though I'd be vary about it).